# How to determine if matrices are similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Trying to teach myself some Linear Algebra, now trying to study about similar matrices concept, but i am having some trouble (maybe because i am trying to teach myself), found a question online and i need to determine if the matrices are similar or not, can you explain how and help solve those?

[image]

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you learned about eigenvalues?  Characteristic polynomials?  Minimal polynomials? Jordan form?

Comment: Ultimately, the best strategy to apply here depends on what you already know or happen to be comfortable with; there are many approaches to this kind of problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer in brief:**

Two matrices are similar if and only if they are similar to the same [Jordan canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) matrix.

An equivalent statement, if you are unfamiliar with Jordan form, is that the matrices $A$ and $B$ are similar if and only if for all $\lambda \in \Bbb C$ and positive integers $k$, we have
$$
\dim \ker[(A - \lambda I)^k] = \dim \ker[(B - \lambda I)^k]
$$
In particular, two diagonalizable matrices are similar if and only if they have the same eigenvalues.

For the first question: note that $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable with the same eigenvalues.  This is enough to conclude that they are similar.

For the second question: note that
$$
\dim \ker(C - I) = 1 \neq \dim \ker (D - I) = 2
$$
In particular, we find that $D$ is diagonalizable, whereas $C$ is not.

Comment: Let me know if there's anything you'd like clarified; maybe I can at least point you in the right direction

Comment: Working on it now, but it looks like i can do it on my on. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $A$ and $B$ have the same Jordan form $J$, then
$$A = PJP^{-1}$$
$$B = QJQ^{-1}$$
and therefore
$$B = Q(P^{-1}AP)Q^{-1} = (PQ^{-1})^{-1}A(PQ^{-1})$$
and $B$ is similar to $A$.

Comment: Can you explain some more? please